# Resource scheduling based on Distance in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, job-scheduling, or-tools

we are developing a resource scheduling algorithm for Transporting goods. Our destinations are fixed say 6 (have geocode details), but our sources (around 1000) might vary every week. we have a constraint is once truck is allocated for particular trip, the next pickup possibly should be nearest to its destination and can do max of 3 trips only per day.

We have build a table with distance of source to destination in DB. While assigning resources (truck) we need advice. Any algorithm would help. I was referencing Google OR tools, will it help. Kindly advice.

Comment: Dijkstra Algorithm???

Comment: Sounds like an optimization problem. These are often solved with genetic algorithms. The fitness factor seems to be fairly calculable since you have the data

Comment: Actually we are looking to arrive at feasible solution rather optimized one

Comment: If you aren't interested in optimization, what do you want? Just linearly assigning the trucks to the nearest source up to 3 times should work unless you have more constraints (e.g. limited trucks)?